# Asynchronically wait for a method to complete in Python 3

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

Consider this simplified example:

```py
def get_external_thing() -> str:
    my_variable = a_blocking_operation()
    my_variable.some_other_operation()
    return my_variable

externally_gathered_thing = None
while True:
    sleep(1)
    externally_gathered_thing = get_external_thing()
    if externally_gathered_thing:
        do_something_1()
        externally_gathered_thing = None
    do_something_2()
```

This will obviously enter the loop, sleep for a second, then go into `get_external_thing()` and wait until `a_blocking_operation()` is finished. Nothing else will be executed as long as `get_external_thing()` is running.

What I'm trying to accomplish is force my loop to continue if `get_external_thing()` is not finished and go straight to `do_something_2()`. However, if `get_external_thing()` is finished and `externally_gathered_thing` has some value, I want `do_something_1()` to be executed as well.

How can I accomplish it purely in Python? I tried to use this example to learn asyncio but didn't manage to produce any working example. Due to project requirements asyncio is a preferred but it's not a must.

In other words, I'd like `do_something_2()` to be executed every second (or every second + some small overhead), regardless of the results of `get_external_thing()`.

Note: don't be scared by the `while True` construct, it's designed to run continuously on a raspberry pi :)

Comment: and when `get_external_thing()` is completed you want to **rerun** it again on next iteration?

Comment: My actual flow is more complicated but, if I get your question right, after `get_external_thing()` is completed, I want `do_something_1()` to be executed, then `externally_gathered_thing` set to None, then `do_something_2()`. But again, it's just a demonstration code. (I updated the code by adding `externally_gathered_thing` inside the `if`)

Comment: again, after that was done, should `get_external_thing()` be **rerun**ed  on next iteration?

Comment: Yes, this would be the preferred flow.

Comment: TBH, not rerunning it on the next iteration wouldn't be that much of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of task look into the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module. For example:

```
def get_external_thing() -> str:
    my_variable = a_blocking_operation()
    my_variable.some_other_operation()
    return my_variable

externally_gathered_thing = None
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
working = None

while True:
    if working is None:
        # if no work is in progress, start the external task in a bg thread
        working = executor.submit(get_external_thing)
    try:
        # wait for the external result, but no more than a second
        externally_gathered_thing = working.result(timeout=1)
        working = None
    except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
        # in case of timeout, proceed with our logic anyway, we'll get
        # back to waiting in the next iteration
        pass

    if externally_gathered_thing is not None:
        do_something_1()
        externally_gathered_thing = None
    do_something_2()
```

An asyncio-based solution is possible, but it would still have to use threads under the hood to await a blocking operation (that's how [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) works), so it would combine the complexity of asyncio with the complexity of threads.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you so much, `Threading` seems to handle this task correctly.

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer and I'll mark it as accepted it there is no asyncio solution in next 2 hours.

Comment: @Artur Asyncio is just not designed to handle blocking calls like `a_blocking_operation()`. You could shoehorn it into asyncio using `run_in_executor`, but it would just end up doing the same thing with threads under the hood, giving you the complexity of asyncio and threads combined, but without the benefits of asyncio (cancellation, etc.).

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced. Thanks for your time!